# Define a method on Schema.ObjectId

Tags: mongoose

I want to define a new method on Schema.ObjectId such that when I call it on an instance of Schema.ObjectId it should invoke that.

```
Schema.ObjectId.truncate = function(){
    return this.toString(0,4) + this.toString(this.length-4);
}

User.findById(id, function(err, user){
    console.log(user.id.truncate());
});
```

Something like above (it doesn't work).

I even tried it on `Schema.ObjectId.prototype` but it says it's undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make one that is called on the document itself instead of the document Id. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that truncate, but here's something along those lines:

```
UserSchema.methods.truncateId = function() {
    var idString = this.id.toString();
    return idString.substr(0, idString.length - 4);
}
```

You call this on `user` itself, not on `user.id`:

```
User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    console.log(user.truncateId());
});
```

Also, ObjectIds don't have length. You need to turn it into a string before calling `.length`.